# Xcode 15, iOS 17 - Archive Failed - File name too long

Tags: swift-data, ios17, xcode15

Working on Xcode 15 GA. I'd like to archive my new iOS 17 project, which works properly on iOS and macOS (includes SwiftData library, new WidgetKit extension and StoreKit). However, when I'm trying to archive the project (either for iOS or macOS) I get an error as follows - "Error opening _.stringsdata for output: File name too long.

I tried everything - still happens. When I'm looking inside the build folder, I see that this error probably related to new @__swiftmacro files. Have no idea how to proceed from here. Blocked from distributing my new app. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The file name should have human-readable snippets that reference parts of your code. Check the code to which the snippets refer and look for a Swift macro. Try refactoring that macro out into a separate function, especially if you're using a macro inside a large block of code, like a SwiftUI view.

Comment: This issue seems to only affect release builds. Are these generated files that represent the macro expansion? Why does this not affect debug builds?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message. In my case I passed the PersistentIdentifiers of SwiftData model objects to the .init function of a new view. Changing this approach to directly inject the model objects as parameters in the .init function solved my issue.